# HTTP Module causing problem with Google Cache

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, httpmodule, google-search, ihttpmodule

I have a live site ( I can't provide the URL ).
It is on sharepoint 2007. The pages were having a URL, later that was modified. 
I wrote a http module and used response.redirect() to navigate user to the correct page.

But since the site was live previously; on searching on google.com, it shows the old URL only. Though the redirection works fine. I need to change the cached URL to new URL.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the different redirect codes - by itself response.redirect() just redirects a browser (or bot) to another address.

You should have been [issuing a 301 redirect](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) then Google and other services (its been roumered that there are a few other games in town) would have eventually removed the old URL and replaced with the new URL and all your 'link juice' would be kept.

> If you need to change the URL of a
>   page as it is shown in search engine
>   results, we recommended that you use a
>   server-side 301 redirect. This is the
>   best way to ensure that users and
>   search engines are directed to the
>   correct page. The 301 status code
>   means that a page has permanently
>   moved to a new location.

ASP.NET code for this

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.addheader "Location", "http://www.newdomain.com/newurl/" 
Response.end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1091779). Not sure, but it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped a lot.